# Hodge decomposition.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, hodge-theory

Let $ X $ be a smooth complex projective algebraic variety of complex dimension $ n $.

Then, there exists the following Hodge decomposition:
$$ H^{2k} (X, \mathbb{C}) = \displaystyle \bigoplus_{p + q = 2k} H^{p, q} (X).
$$

Since $ X $ is a complex manifold, then $ X $ has a real differential manifold structure of real dimension $ 2n $.

My question is the following,

Since $ X $ has a real differential manifold structure, does,
$$ H^{2k} (X, \mathbb{C}) = H_{\mathrm{dR}}^{2k} (X, \mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathbb{C} \qquad ?
$$

- $ H^{2k} (X, \mathbb{C}) $ is the space in the Hodge decomposition formula above.
- $ H_ {\mathrm{dR}}^{2k} (X, \mathbb{R}) $ is the ***real*** deRham cohomology such that any element of this space is a linear combination of ***real*** differential forms for the coordinate system $ (x_1, y_1, \dots, x_n, y_n) $, with ***real*** coefficients.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The answer is yes, but how to go about it depends on what $H^{2k}(X,\mathbb{C})$ means to you? Is it sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}$ or is it the cohomology of the chain complex of complex-valued differential forms? Do you know that these are the same (up to canonical iso)?

Comment: Thank you very much Thorgott. :-) To answer to your question, it is the cohomology of the chain complex of complex-valued differential forms. Can you write me a proof to understand why is $ H^{2k} (X, \mathbb{C}) = H_{\mathrm{dR}}^{2k} (X, \mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathbb{C} $ ? Thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let's denote by $\mathcal{E}^k(X,\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathcal{E}^k(X,\mathbb{R})$ the spaces of complex- and real-valued $k$-forms respectively. The crucial observation is that $\mathcal{E}^k(X,\mathbb{C})\cong\mathcal{E}^k(X,\mathbb{R})\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$, i.e. every complex-valued can be uniquely written as the sum of a real-valued differential form and $i$ times a real-valued differential form (to see this, pick a local frame, expand everything out in terms of the frame and collect the terms containing $i$).  Furthermore, the complex exterior differential $d_{\mathbb{C}}\colon\mathcal{E}^k(X,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow\mathcal{E}^{k+1}(X,\mathbb{C})$ corresponds to the complexification $d_{\mathbb{R}}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}1_{\mathbb{C}}$ of the real exterior differential $d_{\mathbb{R}}\colon\mathcal{E}^k(X,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathcal{E}^{k+1}(X,\mathbb{R})$; indeed, the complex exterior differential is $\mathbb{C}$-linear and agrees with the real exterior differential when restricted to $\mathcal{E}^k(X,\mathbb{R})\subset\mathcal{E}^k(X,\mathbb{C})$. Thus, the chain complex $(\mathcal{E}^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb{C}),d_{\mathbb{C}})$ is just the complexification of the chain complex $(\mathcal{E}^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb{R}),d_{\mathbb{R}})$. It is then a purely algebraic observation that the cohomology of the complexification of a chain complex of real vector spaces is just the complexification of its cohomology.

Comment: Thank you very much Thorgott. :-)

Comment: Sorry @Thorgott again, can you explain to me why is every complex-valued can be uniquely written as the sum of a real-valued differential form and $ i $ times a real-valued differential form. I don't know how to expand everything out in terms of the frame and collect the terms containing $ i $. Can you explicit to me that ? Thank you. :-)

Comment: Choose a local real frame $X_1,\dots,X_n$ for $T^{\ast}U$, $U\subseteq X$ open. Then $X_1,\dots,X_n$ forms a complex frame for $T_{\mathbb{C}}^{\ast}U$, the complexified cotangent bundle. A complex-valued $1$-form is by definition a section of this bundle, so, over $U$, can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i$, where $a_1,\dots,a_n\colon U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ are smooth complex-valued functions. Sepearting $a_1,\dots,a_n$ into real and imaginary parts achieves the desired composition. For general $k$-forms, you do the same thing with the induced frame of the $X_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge X_{i_k}$.

Comment: (Also note that the local decompositions glue together to a global one by uniqueness.)

Comment: Thank you Thorgott. :-)